# How to create createDefaultTabView which return Image and text and set on TabView in short how to set Image & Text together on Custom TabView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view, android-tabs, android-tablelayout

```
//Like this want to return view with image and text
TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
     int width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels /
             mViewPager
             .getAdapter().getCount());
     textView.setMinimumWidth(width-10);
    return textView;
}
```

I have custom Tab not `TabHost` so i cant populate image and text together:

```
//And populate both set on tab
private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (tabView == null) {
        tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());           
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        //Also want to set some selector here

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == i) {
            tabTitleView.setSelected(true);
        }
        tabTitleView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}
```